# Proving the uniqueness of characteristic functions without using Fourier transform theory.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am wondering if there is a way to prove that if two random variables have the same characteristic function, they have the same probability distribution, without using Fourier Transform theory?

**Here is what I got so far:**

What we need to prove is this:

Let $X,Y$ be two real random variables. If

$$E\left[e^{iuX}\right]=E\left[e^{iuY}\right],$$

for every $u \in \mathbb{R}$ then we need to show the distribution for $X$ and $Y$ is the same. That the distribution is the same means that for every $B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ we have

$$E[1_B(X)]=P(X\in B)=P(Y\in B)=E[1_B(Y)].$$

We see that it suffices to show that for any bounded complex function $f:(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))\rightarrow (\mathbb{C},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C}))$ we have

$$E\left[f(X)\right]=E\left[f(Y)\right].$$

I think we maybe can either use a convergence theorem, or a monotone class theorem to finish the proof, but I am not sure how to do it. Do you see how to finish the proof?

Comment: Are you aware of monotone classes and bounded classes of functions?

Comment: @OliverDiaz If you are talking about the monotone class theorem, then yes.

Comment: That is not what I meant. I wrote an answer trying to explain the details. The arguments I present are down as monotone class arguments, it is some sort of expansion of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem that you know from Calculus, but a little more abstract. It has to do with small families of functions that have certain nice properties under limits and generate larger collections that include measurable functions.  You have probably seen this arguments for sets ($\pi$-systems, $\lambda$-systems etc) It takes some time to get an understanding off this, but there you go.

Comment: The Book of Durret (Theory of Probability) and the classical book of Leo Breiman (Probability) cover some of these results. I learnt the presentation I am sketching in my answer from Klaus Bichteler (Integration theory: A functional approach, chapter 2.)

Answer (score 2):

You may approximate $P(a<X<b)$ by a nondecreasing sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ such that $f(x)=0$ for $x\notin (a,b)$ and $f_n(t)\to I\{a<t<b\}$ for each $t$. Thus if $E[f_n(X)]=E[f_n(Y)]$ for all bounded continuous functions with compact support, $X$ and $Y$ have the same distributions by the monotone convergence theorem.

Now let us prove that $E[f(X)]=E[f(Y)]$ for all continuous $f$ with compact support. Assume WLOG that $f$ is supported on $[-b,b]$, and pick a large enough $a>|b|$ such that $P(|X|>a) + P(|Y|>a) \le \epsilon$. Then $f$ is also supported on the larger $[-a,a]$.

Now if $f:R\to C$ is continuous, complex valued with $f(x)=0$ for $x\notin (-a,a)$, we can approximate $f$ on $[-a,a]$ uniformly (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r%27s_theorem) with Fourrier partial sums, say, for large enough $k$,
$\sup_{x\in[-a,a]}|f_k(x) - f(x)| \le \epsilon$ and $f_k$ are sums of the form $\sum_{n=-k}^{k} c_n e^{i x u_n}$ for real numbers $c_n, u_n$ such that $f_k$ is $2a$-periodic. Then
by assumption of equality of characteristic functions $E[f_k(X)] = E[f_k(Y)]$ and
$$
E[f(X) - f(Y)]
= E[f(X) - f_k(X)] - E[f(Y)-f_k(Y)].
$$
Focusing on $\{|X|\le a\}$ and $\{|X|>a\}$ separately,
$$
|E[f(X) - f_k(X)]|
\le \epsilon P(|X|\le a) + P(|X|>a) \max_{|x|>a} |f_k(x)|.
$$
But since $f_k$ is periodic with $f_k(x) = f_k(x+2a)$ for all $x$ we have $\max_{|x|>a} |f_k(x)| = \max_{|x|\le a} |f_k(x)|$ and
$\max_{|x|\le a} |f_k(x)| \le \epsilon + \sup|f|$. In summary,
$$
|E[f(X)] - E[f_k(X)]| \le \epsilon + \epsilon(\epsilon+ \sup|f|).
$$
and the same holds for $Y$. Since this holds for any $\epsilon$ this proves that $E[f(X)]=E[f(Y)]$ for all bounded continuous $f$ supported in $[-a,a]$.

---

Let me mention here that the same proof also provides the result that

> If $X_n$ is a sequence of random variable with charactersitic functions $\phi_n(t)\to \phi(t)$ for all real $t$ where $\phi(t)=E[e^{itX}]$ for some random variable $X$ then $E[f(X_n)]\to E[f(X)]$ for all bounded continuous with compact support, and consequently $X_n\to^d X$ in distribution.

The only new technicality required is to prove that "tightness" holds in the sense that for any $\epsilon$ we have $\sup_n P(|X|>a) \le \epsilon$ for some $a$. We can use the following classical argument that is given in many textbooks. First $\phi(t)$ is continuous at 0, $|1-E[\cos(itX)]\le|1-\phi(t)|\le \epsilon$ for any $t\in(-u,u)$ for some $u\in(0,\pi/8)$ (here $\pi/8$ is not meaningful but we want the sin function to be monotonous on $[-u,u]$. Second,
$$|\frac{1}{2u} \int_{-u}^u (1-\text{Re}\phi_n(t))dt - \frac{1}{2u} \int_{-u}^u (1-\text{Re}\phi_n(t))dt|\le \epsilon
$$
by dominated convergence with respect to the uniform measure on $[-u,u]$ where $\text{Re}$ denotes the real part.
$$
2\epsilon \ge \epsilon+\frac{1}{2u} \int_{-u}^u (1-\text{Re}\phi(t))dt
\ge 
\frac{1}{2u} \int_{-u}^u (1-\text{Re}\phi_n(t)) dt=
\frac{1}{2u} \int_{-u}^u E[1-\cos(tX_n)] dt
= E[1-\sin(uX_n)/(uX_n)]
$$
by Fubini's theorem, and thanks to $
E[1-\sin(uX_n)/(uX_n)]\ge E[1-1/|uX_n|]\ge \frac 12 P(|X_n|>1/u)$. This proves
$$\sup_n (|X_n|>1/u) \le 4 \epsilon.$$

From here, following the same strategy as before, let $f$ be continuous supported om $[-a,a]$ for some $a>|u|$. Using an approximation of $f$ uniformly by some trigonometric polynomial $f_k$ such that
$\sup_{x\in[-a,a]}|f_k(x) - f(x)| \le \epsilon$ (e.g., by Fejer's theorem) we find
$e_n = E[f_k(X)]-E[f_k(X_n)] \to 0$ as $n\to+\infty$ and
$$
E[f(X) - f(X_n)]
= e_n + E[f(X) - f_k(X)] - E[f(X_n)-f_k(X_n)].
$$
Focusing on $\{|X_n|\le u\}$ and $\{|X|>u\}$ separately,
$$
|E[f(X) - f_k(X)]|
\le \epsilon P(|X|\le u) + P(|X|>u) \sup |f_k|
\le \epsilon + 4\epsilon(\epsilon + \sup |f|).
$$
Since $e_n\to0$ this proves $E[f(X_n)]\to E[f(X)]$ for all continuous function with compact support hence $X_n\to^d X$.

Answer (score 1):

The following result

> Suppose that   $\mu$ and $\nu$ are complex measures (measures of finite variation) on $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Then, $\mu=\nu$ iff
> $\widehat{\mu}=\widehat{\nu}$.

can be proven through monotone class arguments. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the collection of all functions of the form  $f_{\bf t}({\bf x})=\exp(i\boldsymbol{x}\cdot \boldsymbol{t})$, $\boldsymbol{t}\in\mathbb{R}^d$.  This is a
complex multiplicative family and contains $\mathbb{1}=f_{\boldsymbol{0}}$.   $\mathcal{M}$ is contained in the space of all bounded complex
valued Borel measurable functions $\mathcal{V}$. The later is a
complex vector space and a bounded class.
By the complex **bounded class theorem**, $\mathcal{V}$ contains all the
bounded complex valued $\sigma(\mathcal{M})$--measurable
functions. In particular, $\mathcal{V}$ contains  all functions of the form
$\mathbb{1}_B$, $B\in\sigma(\mathcal{M})$.
Since $\mu$ and $\nu$ coincide in $\mathcal{M}$, then by dominated
convergence, they also coincide in $\sigma(\mathcal{M})$.
Consider the maps $\gamma_{\bf t}({\bf x})={\bf t\cdot x}$, with
${\bf  t}\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and observe that they generate  $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Since
\begin{align}
\gamma_{\bf t}({\bf x}) = {\bf t\cdot x}=-i\lim_nn(f_{{\bf t}/n}({\bf x})-f_{\bf 0}({\bf x})),
\end{align}
each  $\gamma_{\bf t}$ is  $\sigma(\mathcal{M})$-measurable. Therefore
$\sigma(\mathcal{M})=\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\mu=\nu$.

---

Here are more or less the tools that make this argument work:

A few definitions:

- A collection  $\mathcal{V}\subset\mathbb{R}^\Omega$, is a
  ***monotone class*** if it is closed under taking pointwise limits of
  monotone convergent sequences.
- A collection  $\mathcal{V}\subset\mathcal{B}_b(\Omega;\mathbb{R})$ is a ***bounded monotone class*** if it is  closed under taking pointwise limits of  uniformly bounded monotone sequences.
- A collection $\mathcal{V}\subset\mathcal{B}_b(\Omega;\mathbb{F})$, where $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$,   is
  a ***bounded class*** if it is closed under taking pointwise limits of uniformly bounded convergent sequences.
- A collection  $\mathcal{M}\subset\mathbb{R}^\Omega$
  is a ***real multiplicative class***  if it is closed under finite multiplication.
- A collection  $\mathcal{M}\subset\mathbb{C}^\Omega$ of complex valued
  functions is a
  ***complex multiplicative class***  if it is  closed under finite multiplication and under complex conjugation.

**Theorem:** *(Complex bounded class theorem).*  Suppose $\mathcal{V}\subset\mathcal{B}_b(\Omega;\mathbb{C})$ is a complex vector space,   a complex bounded class, and contains the constant function $\mathbb{1}$. If $\mathcal{M}\subset\mathcal{V}$ is complex multiplicative class, then $\mathcal{V}$ contains the collection of all bounded $\mathbb{C}$--valued $\sigma(\mathcal{M})$--measurable functions.

Comment: I don't see what you mean with "since they coincide in $M$ then by dominated convergence they coincide in $\sigma(M)$"

Comment: @reuns: I meant to say that as $\mu f=\nu f$ for all $f\in\mathcal{M}$, then $\mu h=\nu h$ for all $\sigma(\mathcal{M})$--measurable functions $h$ for any such $h$ is the limit of functions in $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: Yes but why. Limit in what sense. You are hiding the key argument..

Comment: pointwise limits. For example $\{f>1\}=\lim_n1\wedge(n(f-f\wedge1))$.

Comment: Pointwise limit plus another condition if you want to apply the DCT (which is not needed as shown in my answer).

Comment: Sure, in fact that can be monotone sequences.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. You are jumping from finite linear combinations of exponentials to $L^\infty$ without trying to clarify at all.

Comment: @reuns: the type of limits (point wise) are more or less stated in the complex bounded class theorem. I decided not to go through all the details since it will take me a long time and space to get all the pieces together. If you want, I can give you another reference that contains more details (also by Klaus)

Comment: No $L_\infty$ is involve.Everything is based on monotone class theorems for functions.

Comment: Rick Durret, Probability Theory, %th edition, Chapter 5 has a (real) monotone class theorem; Klaus Bichteler, Stochastic integration, appendix A.3 has a detailed presentation of the (real and complex) monotone class theorem and the relations with sequential closure and sequential spans.

Answer (score 0):

1. With $f_X,f_Y$ the probability distributions, if $f_X-f_Y$ is non-zero then for $T$ large enough you'll have that $$g(x)=\sum_k (f_X(x-2\pi kT)-f_Y(x-2\pi kT))$$ is a non-zero $2\pi T$-periodic distribution and a non-zero finite signed measure on $[0,2\pi T)$.
2. The key is that for all $m\in \Bbb{Z}$ $$\int_0^{2\pi T}e^{ixm/T} g(x)dx=\int_\Bbb{R} e^{i xm/T}f_X(x)dx-\int_\Bbb{R} e^{i xm/T}f_Y(x)dx=0$$
3. Therefore we also have  $\int_0^{2\pi T} (\frac{1+\cos(\frac{x-a}{T})}{2})^ng(x)dx\ne 0$ for all $a,n$.
4. Take a $2\pi T$-periodic continuous function such that $\int_0^{2\pi T} \phi(x)g(x)dx\ne 0$, take $n,L$ large enough to approximate $\phi$ with $$\phi_{L,n}(x)=\frac{1}{C_n L} \sum_{l=0}^{L-1} \phi(\frac{2\pi T l}{L}) (\frac{1+\cos(\frac{x-\frac{2\pi T l}{L}}{T})}{2})^n$$ ($C_n=\int_0^{2\pi T} (\frac{1+\cos(\frac{x}{T})}{2})^ndx$)

   Since $g(x)dx$ is a finite measure on $[0,2\pi T)$ you'll have that $\int_0^{2\pi T} \phi_{L,n}(x)g(x)dx\approx  \int_0^{2\pi T} \phi(x)g(x)dx\ne 0$, contradicting the point 3.